# Set background color of a TreeNode

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a TreeView like so:

```
System.Windows.Forms.TreeView treeView;
this.treeView = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeView();

treeView.Update();
treeNode = this.treeView.Nodes.Add(yadda1);
treeNode = this.treeView.Nodes.Add(yadda2);
treeNode = this.treeView.Nodes.Add(yadda3);

foreach (TreeNode node in treeView.Nodes)
{
    namedNode = getTreeNodeFromName(documentType, node);
    if (namedNode != null)
    {
        break; // found it
    }
}
treeView.SelectedNode = namedNode;
treeView.SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.Blue;
treeView.Focus();
this.treeView.EndUpdate();
```

This code almost works. By default, the selected node is indicated by the background color being a very light grey, difficult to see. So I programmatically set it to Blue, but the background doesn't turn to Blue until the user clicks on another node.

A previous question suggests calling `treeView.Focus()` but this makes no difference.

How do I get the background color to go to Blue immediately?

Comment: You are trying to change the system's highlight color.  To do that, you will have to draw the nodes yourself.  See DrawMode property and the DrawNode event.

Comment: LarsTech is correct, If you wish to do this you must answer the DrawNode Event. It's actually fairly simple. This should get you started. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: Some LCD monitors have trouble displaying unsaturated colors like this one well enough.  Not mine, and I doubt I'd much appreciate a program overriding it.  Given that this affects every program on your machine, the logical solution is to just change the system color.

Comment: @HansPassant: I think changing the color of the TreeView within my application would affect only my application, not every program on my machine. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to do it. Directly inherit from the TreeView class. This just gets the basics of drawing the text portion of the node. I'm still working on the 'lines' part but that will have to wait until I return home. However, this will get you started and shows an alternate way to do what you want. Deriving from the control to create your own class is very powerful and allows the greatest flexibility, but also requires the greatest level of effort. Even so, it's not monumental.

```
public class CustomTreeView : TreeView
{
    public CustomTreeView() : base()
    {
        this.SetStyle(
            ControlStyles.UserPaint |
            ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer |
            ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (System.Drawing.SolidBrush BackGroundBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window))
        using (System.Drawing.SolidBrush ForeGroundBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText))
        using (System.Drawing.SolidBrush BackGroundBrushHighLight = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen))
        using (System.Drawing.SolidBrush ForeGroundBrushHighLight = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Pink))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(BackGroundBrush, e.ClipRectangle);
            System.Drawing.SolidBrush CurrentNode;

            int count = this.Nodes.Count;
            for (int index = 0; index < count; ++index)
            {
                if (Nodes[index].IsSelected)
                {
                    CurrentNode = ForeGroundBrushHighLight;
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(BackGroundBrushHighLight, Nodes[index].Bounds);
                }
                else
                {
                    CurrentNode = ForeGroundBrush;
                }
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Nodes[index].Text, this.Font, CurrentNode, Rectangle.Inflate(Nodes[index].Bounds, 2, 0));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will be trying this. I've implemented code as you've suggested in the link in your comment and the basics work, but there are problems with the details. I mess with them for a while, then try this class.

Comment: I'm working on using this class and have encountered a problem. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44073076/custom-treeview-class-displays-unwanted-characters)

Comment: @AlLelopath, I'm sorry I never got the lines. The list of things you'll need to support in the drawing are: 1) lines that also handle child nodes, 2) outlining so that the user may hide entire child structures, and 3) indentation for child nodes. There's a lot but each one is surmountable. If that sounds like more than you want to tackle then you always have the option to go back to the owner draw technique. Personally, I would encourage you to continue with this approach, as once you're done you'll have learned a lot about painting which will open up more possibilities for customization in C#

Comment: Can you explain why people are hatin' on using `OnPaint()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077816/position-of-text-and-background-in-treeview) saying that one should instead use the DrawMode property?

Comment: It's a different way to do it. OnPaint requires that you do everything. So, it does mean more work.