# Position of text and background in TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a custom TreeView class. I don't like how the text and the background color line up. The text appears to high (or background too low):

[image]

I don't see any way of positioning the text, so I've tried moving the Y position of the background up 2 pixels. This causes lines to appear when
clicking from one node to another:

[image]

I think the previous node background is not being redrawn, though I think I have the code for that, in `CustomTreeView.OnPaint()`, in the `else // not selected` section

Is there anything I can do about this or is this just the way it has to be?

```
public class CustomTreeView : TreeView
    {
        public CustomTreeView() : base()
        {
            this.SetStyle(
                ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer |
                ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using (System.Drawing.SolidBrush BackGroundBrushWindows = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window))
            using (System.Drawing.SolidBrush ForeGroundBrushWindows = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText))
            using (System.Drawing.SolidBrush BackGroundBrushHighLight = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.CornflowerBlue))
            //using (System.Drawing.SolidBrush ForeGroundBrushHighLight = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(BackGroundBrushWindows, e.ClipRectangle);
                System.Drawing.SolidBrush CurrentNode;

                int count = this.Nodes.Count;
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("\nCustomTreeView.OnPaint: count: " + count);
                for (int topLevelIndex = 0; topLevelIndex < count; ++topLevelIndex)
                {
                    TreeNode topLevelTreeNode = Nodes[topLevelIndex];
                    CurrentNode = ForeGroundBrushWindows; // top level always this, never selected
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(topLevelTreeNode.Text, this.Font, CurrentNode, Rectangle.Inflate(topLevelTreeNode.Bounds, 2, 0));

                    int nodeCount = topLevelTreeNode.GetNodeCount(true);
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("OnPaint: Nodes[index].GetNodeCount: " + nodeCount);

                    foreach (TreeNode childNode in topLevelTreeNode.Nodes)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("\tchildNode: " + childNode.Tag + "\tIsSelected: " + childNode.IsSelected);
                        if (childNode.IsSelected)
                        {
                            //CurrentNode = ForeGroundBrushWindows;
                            Rectangle bounds = childNode.Bounds;
                            //bounds.Y += -2; // move up 2
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(BackGroundBrushHighLight, bounds);
                        }
                        else // not selected
                        {
                            //CurrentNode = ForeGroundBrushWindows;
                            Rectangle bounds = childNode.Bounds;
                            //bounds.Y += -2; // move up 2
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(BackGroundBrushWindows, bounds);
                        }

                        if (childNode.Parent.IsExpanded)
                        {
                            Rectangle bounds = childNode.Bounds;
                            //bounds.Y += -2; // move up 2
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(childNode.Text, this.Font, CurrentNode, Rectangle.Inflate(bounds, 2, 0));
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

      public partial class TreeViewDialog : Form
    {

        //  Add unselectable nodes to this collection when you create them
        private List<TreeNode> _unselectableNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

        public TreeViewDialog (String documentType)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            this.treeView.Update();

            // Add (key, text), where key is name of the tree node and text is the text to display
            TreeNode treeNodeClassical = this.treeView.Nodes.Add(ProjectConstants.TOP_NODE_CLASSICAL, ProjectConstants.TOP_NODE_CLASSICAL);
            treeNodeClassical.Tag = ProjectConstants.TOP_NODE_CLASSICAL;
            _unselectableNodes.Add(treeNodeClassical);

            TreeNode treeNode = treeNodeClassical.Nodes.Add(ProjectConstants.CLASSICAL_BEETHOVEN, ProjectConstants.CLASSICAL_BEETHOVEN);
            treeNode.Tag = ProjectConstants.CLASSICAL_BEETHOVEN;
            treeNode = treeNodeClassical.Nodes.Add(ProjectConstants.CLASSICAL_MOZART, ProjectConstants.CLASSICAL_MOZART);
            treeNode.Tag = ProjectConstants.CLASSICAL_MOZART;
            treeNode = treeNodeClassical.Nodes.Add(ProjectConstants.CLASSICAL_CHOPIN, ProjectConstants.CLASSICAL_CHOPIN);
            treeNode.Tag = ProjectConstants.CLASSICAL_CHOPIN;

            TreeNode treeNodeJazz = this.treeView.Nodes.Add(ProjectConstants.TOP_NODE_JAZZ, ProjectConstants.TOP_NODE_JAZZ);
            treeNodeJazz.Tag = ProjectConstants.TOP_NODE_JAZZ;
            _unselectableNodes.Add(treeNodeJazz);

            treeNode = treeNodeJazz.Nodes.Add(ProjectConstants.JAZZ_MONK, ProjectConstants.JAZZ_MONK);
            treeNode.Tag = ProjectConstants.JAZZ_MONK;
            treeNode = treeNodeJazz.Nodes.Add(ProjectConstants.JAZZ_MINGUS, ProjectConstants.JAZZ_MINGUS);
            treeNode.Tag = ProjectConstants.JAZZ_MINGUS;
            treeNode = treeNodeJazz.Nodes.Add(ProjectConstants.JAZZ_COLTRANE, ProjectConstants.JAZZ_COLTRANE);
            treeNode.Tag = ProjectConstants.JAZZ_COLTRANE;
            treeNode = treeNodeJazz.Nodes.Add(ProjectConstants.JAZZ_GILLESPIE, ProjectConstants.JAZZ_GILLESPIE);
            treeNode.Tag = ProjectConstants.JAZZ_GILLESPIE;


            TreeNode treeNodeRock = this.treeView.Nodes.Add(ProjectConstants.TOP_NODE_ROCK, ProjectConstants.TOP_NODE_ROCK);
            treeNodeRock.Tag = ProjectConstants.TOP_NODE_ROCK;
            _unselectableNodes.Add(treeNodeRock);

            treeNode = treeNodeRock.Nodes.Add(ProjectConstants.ROCK_CORNELL, ProjectConstants.ROCK_CORNELL);
            treeNode.Tag = ProjectConstants.ROCK_CORNELL;
            treeNode = treeNodeRock.Nodes.Add(ProjectConstants.ROCK_PLANT, ProjectConstants.ROCK_PLANT);
            treeNode.Tag = ProjectConstants.ROCK_PLANT;
            treeNode = treeNodeRock.Nodes.Add(ProjectConstants.ROCK_BJORK, ProjectConstants.ROCK_BJORK);
            treeNode.Tag = ProjectConstants.ROCK_BJORK;
            treeNode = treeNodeRock.Nodes.Add(ProjectConstants.ROCK_SPRINGSTEEN, ProjectConstants.ROCK_SPRINGSTEEN);
            treeNode.Tag = ProjectConstants.ROCK_SPRINGSTEEN;
            treeNode = treeNodeRock.Nodes.Add(ProjectConstants.ROCK_LADY_GAGA, ProjectConstants.ROCK_LADY_GAGA);
            treeNode.Tag = ProjectConstants.ROCK_LADY_GAGA;

            this.treeView.ExpandAll();

            // if something was selected on the tab page, then select it here
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(documentType))
            {
                TreeNode namedNode = null;
                foreach (TreeNode node in treeView.Nodes)
                {
                    namedNode = getTreeNodeFromName(documentType, node);
                    if (namedNode != null)
                    {
                        break; // nothing found
                    }
                }

                if (namedNode != null)
                {
                    treeView.SelectedNode = namedNode; 
                }
                treeView.Focus();

            }

            this.treeView.EndUpdate();
        }

        public TreeNode getTreeNodeFromName(string name, TreeNode rootNode)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in rootNode.Nodes)
            {
                if (node.Name.Equals(name))
                {
                    return node;
                }
                TreeNode next = getTreeNodeFromName(name, node);
                if (next != null)
                {
                    return next;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // nothing right now
        }


        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void treeViewCategoryType_TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs eventArgs)
        {            TreeView treeView = (TreeView)sender;

            TreeNode treeNode = eventArgs.Node; // parent or child

            String nodeText = treeNode.Text;

            // if parent treeNode
            if (nodeText.Equals(ProjectConstants.TOP_NODE_CLASSICAL) ||
                nodeText.Equals(ProjectConstants.TOP_NODE_JAZZ) ||
                nodeText.Equals(ProjectConstants.TOP_NODE_ROCK))
            {
                // don't select the treeNode
            }
            else
            {  // child
            }

        }

        private void treeViewCategoryType_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (_unselectableNodes.Contains(eventArgs.Node))
            {
                eventArgs.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what's the goal, but you are doing it wrong. Instead of trying to paint yourself everything, set [`DrawMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawmode(v=vs.110).aspx) property to other than `Normal` and handle the [`DrawNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode(v=vs.110).aspx) event - see the example in the link.

Comment: Using e.ClipRectangle is quite wrong, it does something completely different.  You have to use TreeNode.Bounds.  The entire approach is highly questionable, no telling what other kind of trouble you'll run into.  TreeView supports custom-draw, but you have to set the DrawMode property and implement the DrawNode event.  If you have a specific reason to do this then you should mention it.

Comment: @HansPassant: The reason for doing this is that the background and text are not centered vertically with each other (as show in the first image).

Comment: Not what I meant, nobody can tell why you don't do this the correct way.  Which is using the DrawMode property.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. The answer below works. Why is this way incorrect? Will it result in memory leak? Slow execution? something else bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this at `OnPaint`,

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(childNode.Text, this.Font, CurrentNode, Rectangle.Inflate(bounds, 2, -3));
```

`DrawString` function's last parameter accepts a Rectangle and that rectangle has Y value as you desired. 0 is the unwanted that you told, so it should have minus values to push text to bottom.

Hope helps,

Comment: You are correct in that that is the value to manipulate. -3 is a little too high. -1 looks best. However, the lines as shown in the 2nd image still appear.

Comment: I copied your code but not working like the previous question. Can you provide full code? I worked with the other code that you shared previous question and there was not any lines.Undo your changes about changing background position that might cause it. @AlLelopath

Comment: yep my mistake.